# Compress Json data in hive external table, at the time querying throwing exception?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I  have created external tables by following below steps

```
Hive >  ADD JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
Hive > set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
Hive > set mapred.output.compress=true;
Hive> set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
Hive> set io.compression.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;

Hive >  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Json (id BIGINT,created_at STRING,source STRING,favorited BOOLEAN) ROW FORMAT SERDE  "com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe"
LOCATION  /user/cloudera/ jsonGZ ";
```

I have compressed my Json file  by executing below command

```
“ hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar -Dmap.output.compress=true  -Dmap.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec -Dmapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true -Dmapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec -input /user/cloudera/json/ -output /user/cloudera/jsonGZ “
```

Then when I am running  `“  select * from  json; “` I am getting the below error:

```
“OK Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token at “
```

And also I have created one more table  using  “org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerD”

```
Hive >  ADD JAR /usr/lib/hive-hactalog/share/ hactalog/ hive-hactalog-core.jar;

Hive > CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Json 1(id BIGINT,created_at STRING,source STRING,favorited BOOLEAN) ROW FORMAT SERDE  "com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe"
LOCATION  /user/cloudera/ jsonGZ ";
```

Then when I am running  `“select * from  json1;“`,I am getting the below error:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException: Start token not found where expected" after using "org.apache.hive.hcatalog.core(hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar)"
```

Am I missing something? How can I resolve this errors.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the precise characters used in the commands.  In several cases, you have "curly quotes", missing quotes, spaces, and double quotes -- SQL strings must (typically) be enclosed in a single quote like this `'` not `"` or `“`.  So it doesn't look like some of these queries could work at all.  Then, work backwards by starting without compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just gzip your files and put them as is (*.gz) into the table location.

gzip filename